# Ask Siri for battery level on Apple TV remote

Tags: battery, appletv, siri, remote-control, siri-remote

On our Apple TV 4K, we were previously able to ask Siri on the remote control “battery level”. The current amount of battery charge appeared on screen.

That feature disappeared in recent versions of tvOS. Now to see the battery level, we must dig through multiple layers in the Settings app.

Is there some way to simply ask Siri about the battery level of the remote control?